# How to get the text value from a dropdown

Tags: php

I have a dropdown populated by a db. 
I need to add the text value and the id to another table. Im using this to get the value and id.

```
$catid = intval($_POST['cat']); // This line is meant to assign the id to $catid
$cat = $_POST['cat']; // This line is meant to assign the text value to $cat
```

But both lines assign the id to the variables!
I'm sure its a simple fix but i cant figure it out!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide the HTML code and the content of $_POST

Comment: What do you expect `intval` to do?  What is doing instead?  Can you show us what value you have in `$_POST['cat']`?

Comment: In a normalized relational database, you should never need anything but an `id` of another table.  However, if you really need it, you would need to do a lookup first (using the `id` you get in the `POST`)

Answer (score 4):

`intval` takes a string and converts it to an integer. It will only really work if the string contains at least one integer already. So if your variable is `$foo = '5';` then `intval()` will convert the `string 5` to the `integer 5`. It doesn't do anything else. So if the category you're submitting is a string version of the id, then yes, both variables will be the id. One as a string, and one as an int.

You cannot submit both the value of an HTML option, and the inner text of it. Only the value property. If no value is present, it will use the inner html/text.

`<option value="1">MyCat</option>` -- the only thing sent via POST is 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
$cat = strval($_POST['cat']);
```

Use strval() to convert an int to string.